# how to add target for button in subViewController of controller

Tags: ios, subclass, target

a have 2 controller

```
@interface PlayVideoController : UIViewController
```

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *exportButton;
- (IBAction)actionPlay:(id)sender;
and

```
@interface HomeController : CommonVideoViewController
```

in Homecontroller have 2 method

```
    - (void)selectedVideoComplete:(NSDictionary *)infoVideo 
    playController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlayVideoController"];
//    playController = [[PlayVideoController alloc]initWithNibName:@"View" bundle:nil];

//    [playController.playtButton addTarget:playController action:@selector(playAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    playController.urlMovie = [infoVideo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    [self.view addSubview:playController.view];
     NSLog(@"_____ %@",playController.playButton);
    [playController.view addSubview:btn];

- (void)playAction {
    [playController.player play];
}
```

why this code does not work

```
[playController.playtButton addTarget:playController action:@selector(playAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

i am test using storyboard and xib file

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are implementing the `playAction` method in your `HomeController`, and it needs to be implemented in you `PlayVideoController`.

Or if your `playAction` method is only doing what your code shows it as doing, just set the action as follows:

```
[playController.playButton addTarget:playController.player action:@selector(play) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Hope this helps!